# How can I make a Genus 3 Surface?

Tags: modeling

I would like to create a [Genus 3 Surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_g_surface) (i.e. a "triple torus") like this one:

[image: Text]

Ideally, its topology should be fairly decent (unlike the one in the picture) and I'd rather not make this surface out of the [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) of three separate tori. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, create a torus, make it as simple as possible, like 16x8 vertices, move it away from its origin on Y or X axis in *Edit* mode, duplicate and rotate 120° twice with the 3D cursor as axis of rotation, cut a hole on each one:

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* between these vertices:

[image]

Do the same all around, continue to fill the faces until you get that:

[image]

Create an edge loop around each bridge:

[image]

Merge these 3 inner vertices at center:

[image]

Scale these edge loops except on Z:

[image]

Result with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and *Shade Smooth*:

[image]

Comment: R + Z for stress relief

Answer (score 8):

If you are a person who likes to start from top view in 2D, you can try this method starting with a circle with 8 vertices, inset, remove face, add Loop Cut, and duplicate it 2 times around the 3D Cursor by 120 degrees.

[image]

Then select the outer edge loops and inner circle edge loops for the top and the bottom of the geometry, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to uniformly scale it to approximate the Torus shape.

[image]

Final result with *Subdivision Surface Modifier* and *Shade Smooth*.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without creating anything too complicated, you can run this script and with a little mesh cleanup you can get something close. Make it in a new scene because it will remove everything in the scene.

[image: Thing]

```
import bpy

def create_genus_3_surface():
    # Clear existing mesh objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    
    # Create first torus
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(
        align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0),
        rotation=(0, 0, 0), 
        major_radius=2, minor_radius=0.5
    )
    torus1 = bpy.context.object
    
    # Create second torus
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(
        align='WORLD', location=(4, 0, 0),
        rotation=(0, 0, 0), 
        major_radius=2, minor_radius=0.5
    )
    torus2 = bpy.context.object

    # Create third torus
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(
        align='WORLD', location=(2, 4, 0),
        rotation=(0, 0, 0),
        major_radius=2, minor_radius=0.5
    )
    torus3 = bpy.context.object

    # Use boolean modifiers to merge the tori
    torus1.modifiers.new(name="BooleanTorus2", type='BOOLEAN')
    torus1.modifiers["BooleanTorus2"].operation = 'UNION'
    torus1.modifiers["BooleanTorus2"].object = torus2
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"object": torus1}, modifier="BooleanTorus2")
    
    torus1.modifiers.new(name="BooleanTorus3", type='BOOLEAN')
    torus1.modifiers["BooleanTorus3"].operation = 'UNION'
    torus1.modifiers["BooleanTorus3"].object = torus3
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"object": torus1}, modifier="BooleanTorus3")

    # Delete the original second and third tori
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    torus2.select_set(True)
    torus3.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    # Apply a smooth shading to the final object
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    torus1.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()

    # Optionally, add a subdivision surface modifier to further smooth the result
    torus1.modifiers.new(name="Subdivision", type='SUBSURF')
    torus1.modifiers["Subdivision"].levels = 2
    torus1.modifiers["Subdivision"].render_levels = 2

# Call the function
create_genus_3_surface()
```

Comment: This is a nice interesting answer, however I decided to accept moonbots' answer since it doesn't require scripts which sadly I'm not too familiar with (I'm still learning the basics of Blender). But I appreciate it and will come back to this answer when I'm ready

Comment: This might work but the resulting topology from boolean operations is going to create shading artifacts.