# How can I uniformly scale a set of faces on the XY plane similar to Inset or Shrink/Fatten?

Tags: modeling, transforms, edges, faces

In [this thread exercise](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/300255/142292) I stumbled upon a problem where I realized that scaling the middle edge loop outward to create a torus approximation does not work as it is not scaling uniformly. The [`Shrink/Fatten`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shrink-fatten.html) with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will work, but it will pinch the geometry when applying Subdivision Modifier.

[image]

So instead of scaling the middle edge loop outward, I wanted to find a workaround and do something that scales the upper and lower outer edge loops inward on only the XY plane, similar to the behavior of the Inset feature.

[image]

So I tried [`Shrink/Fatten`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shrink-fatten.html), but unlike in the case of the middle edge loop, this will now also scale the Z component. I was wondering if there is a scale similar to the Inset feature that would operate only on the XY plane?

[image]

Comment: I've edited my answer because I forgot the most obvious solution :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**//EDIT:** Below you will find workarounds, but sorry, I forgot the most obvious. So first of all the solution: If you have the *Edit Mesh Tools* enabled, just select the top and bottom outer edges and choose *Edge* > *Offset Edges* > *Move* and enter a negative value for *Width*.

[image: offset edges move]

[image: width value]

And now for the workarounds if you do not want to use the *Edit Mesh Tools* for whatever reason:

The first solution that comes to my mind as a workaround would be to bevel the top and bottom edge with one segment, then selecting the beveled inner edges which moved towards the middle edge and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*. Not great, but not too complicated and does the job as a workaround. And you can enter a value if you want an exact distance to move inwards.

[image: bevel edges]

[image: dissolve inner edges]

But since you mention the *Inset* feature, why not use that? Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then deselect the outer face loops by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking the vertical edges between them. Afterwards you can dissolve the top and bottom outer edges. Of course you can enter a value here as well.

[image: select all but outer edges]

[image: inset faces]

Comment: Oh yeah I have the Mesh Edit Tools thing, the Edge Offset pretty useful, thank you very much for sharing Gordon!